# CSS dropdown menu doesn't display when link is hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of a problem with my pure CSS dropdown menu, when I add CSS properties to the footer and the container div the sub menu doesn't stay displayed.

I don't really know how I can correct this problem, I've tried looking for answers on google but I can't find any answer that'll fix my problem.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: OpenSans, Noto, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Tahoma, Arial, FreeSans, sans-serif;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background: #505050;
  padding: 5px;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00c308;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-top: 55px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-top: 1px #D1D1D1 solid;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #5d5d5d;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px grey;
}
#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  background: #5d5d5d;
}
nav ul li a {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 11px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.sous_menu {
  display: none;
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
}
.sous_menu a {
  color: black;
}
.sous_menu a:hover {
  background: #00ce08;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: #00c308;
}
nav ul li:hover>.sous_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1080px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  min-height: 700px;
}
footer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #505050;
}
```

[here is the jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sLrocmwz/)

Thank you in advance

EDIT: Thanks for your answers the problem is resolved. thank you all for your help and answers

Comment: What is your goal with the menu items being display: flex?

Comment: this problem occurs mostly when you don't use `position:relative`

Comment: Problem is not present in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.sous_menu`

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: OpenSans,Noto,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,FreeSans,sans-serif;
}

header{
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 110px;
 background: #505050;
 padding: 5px;
}

#logo{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #00c308;
 padding: 5px;
 padding-top: 55px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
}

nav{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 border-top: 1px #D1D1D1 solid;
 position: static;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background: #5d5d5d;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px grey;
}

#menu{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1080px;
}

nav ul{
 display: flex;
 max-width: 1080px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 49px;
 list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;
 background: #5d5d5d;
}

nav ul li a{
 box-sizing: content-box;
 padding: 11px 0px;
 width:100%;
 font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue" ;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #EEEEEE;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 100;
}

.sous_menu{
 display: none;
    position: relative;
 max-width: 1080px;
 width: 100%;
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
}

.sous_menu a{
 color: black;
}

.sous_menu a:hover{
 background: #00ce08;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
 color: white;
 background: #00c308;
}

nav ul li:hover>.sous_menu{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#container{
 display:flex;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 max-width: 1080px;
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
 min-height: 700px;
}

footer{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #505050;
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <header>
   <div id="logo">T</br>N</br>I N F O</div>
  </header>
  
  <nav>
   <div id="menu">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Ordinateurs</a>
      <div class="sous_menu">
       <a href="#">PC de Bureau</a>
       <a href="#">PC Portables</a>
       <a href="#">Accessoires</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Peripheriques</a>
      <div class="sous_menu">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Hardware</a>
      <div class="sous_menu">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Software</a>
      <div class="sous_menu">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
       <a href="#">Link 2</a>
       <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
    
    
   </div>
  </nav>
  
  <div id="container">
   <div id="news">
   </div>
   
   
  </div>
  
  <footer>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add `position:relative;` to `nav ul li`:

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: OpenSans,Noto,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Tahoma,Arial,FreeSans,sans-serif;
}

header{
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 110px;
 background: #505050;
 padding: 5px;
}

#logo{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #00c308;
 padding: 5px;
 padding-top: 55px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 12px;
}

nav{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 border-top: 1px #D1D1D1 solid;
 position: static;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background: #5d5d5d;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px grey;
}

#menu{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1080px;
}

nav ul{
 display: flex;
 max-width: 1080px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 49px;
 list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex: 1;
 text-align: center;
 background: #5d5d5d;
  position:relative;
}

nav ul li a{
 box-sizing: content-box;
 padding: 11px 0px;
 width:100%;
 font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue" ;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #EEEEEE;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 100;
}

.sous_menu{
 display: none;
 max-width: 1080px;
 width: 100%;
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
}

.sous_menu a{
 color: black;
}

.sous_menu a:hover{
 background: #00ce08;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
 color: white;
 background: #00c308;
}

nav ul li:hover>.sous_menu{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

#container{
 display:flex;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 max-width: 1080px;
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
 min-height: 700px;
}

footer{
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #505050;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">T
      <br>N
      <br>I N F O</div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Ordinateurs</a>
          <div class="sous_menu">
            <a href="#">PC de Bureau</a>
            <a href="#">PC Portables</a>
            <a href="#">Accessoires</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Peripheriques</a>
          <div class="sous_menu">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Hardware</a>
          <div class="sous_menu">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Software</a>
          <div class="sous_menu">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="news">
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
  </footer>
```

Also, your `br` tags have the slash in the wrong place - they should be after the `br`

Answer (score 0):

Add relative position to parent `li` using `position:relative;`

```
nav ul li{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    background: #5d5d5d;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is to add this: `nav ul li:hover > a,`
When hovering the `li`, the first anchor gets highlighted as well.

```
nav ul li:hover > a,
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: #00c308;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLrocmwz/2/)**

*Edit: I hope I didn't missunderstand your question :)*

Comment: Note: Your fiddle works as you expect in Firefox, not in Chrome though. Whoever downvoted, please at least explain your votes.